# Disputed "not an answer" flag for question 689439

Tags: discussion, disputed-flags

I recently flagged [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/874580) as *not an answer* since it is a thank you comment that duplicates the second part of [this existing answer](https://superuser.com/a/731182). However, the flag was marked as disputed for some reason.

I seem to recall there was another thank you answer there as well as the time which I thought I had flagged as well, but now I can't see any record of it. Still, I am wondering if it could be worth protecting the question since it is getting a lot of views and a lot of low  quality answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the community thought it was fit as an answer.

Here's the reviews:

- https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/339646
- https://superuser.com/review/late-answers/339645

Wouldn't disagree with that thought when viewed just from a review queue point of view(which doesn't show the others answers - but ideally you *are* supposed to look at other answers too).

Perhaps a custom mod flag stating 'bulk of answer copy-pasted from an existing answer' would have been a better choice. Anyway, the post is now auto protected(there are 6 deleted non-answers/me-too posts)